# Objects touching other objects

Tags: objective-c, xcode, object, draggable

I would really love if someone could tell me how to tell whether 2 objects have touched (An image or a button) I know how to make them draggable but not how to tell if they have touched and to do something when they touch!

Thanks!

Comment: check the coordinates/frames of each view and see if they overlap or are the same

Answer (score 2):

If you never rotate the objects, you can use CoreGraphics functions.

```
BOOL objectsTouch = CGRectIntersectsRect(object1.frame, object2.frame);
```

This requires of course that the two objects are in the same superview. Otherwise you have to transform the frames using functions of the NSView.

Comment: +1, this is probably the most efficient way to do it. Should go without saying, but this is comparing frame rects, so you may get unexpected (but correct) results if your image is circular or something.

Answer (score 0):

The classical approach is to calculate a minimal circle that encompasses each object, then calculate the distance between circle centers (Pythagorean theorem) and see if it's less than R(object1 circle) + R(object2 circle).  If less then you have to get down and dirty with bit mapping or some other scheme, but if greater then you can assume the objects don't touch.